# How to parse blank response headers with Rest Assured

Tags: java, selenium, http, get, rest-assured

I'm currently trying to implement a GET API request using REST Assured in java. I can use Insomnia and Postman to successfully complete the request which means I know there isn't an issue with the request itself:

[Isomnia Successful Response Header Parsing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wd7b.png)

...but REST Assured seems to have a problem parsing the blank response headers. I followed the Exception stack trace down to the REST Assured AbstractMessageParser.java to discover it is failing at line 228:

[AbstractMessageParser.java snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eEtI.png)

It is successfully parsing the response headers with content but then fails when there is no content. This seems like a bug in Rest Assured unless there is something else I am not doing correctly.

Has anyone else seen this before?

Comment: Did you have a check at this ? https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#default-parser

Comment: @WilfredClement Tried that out but doesn't seem to make a difference. Still seeing a ClientProtocolException when it tries to parse the response headers. Thanks for the tip though!